# SQL Optimization - where not exists self join

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

Please provide advice on how to optimize this sql procedure... the where not exists subselect is my main issue. I have been told I can get a 40% performance increase.

```
   insert into #tmpTable (intID3,intID4,intID5,intID6, 
          StaticDate,NewDate, 
          [Description],Change,intSort) 
   select distinct 
          '' as intID3,           
          intID4,
          intID5, 
          intID6, 
          @dteDate1 as StaticDate, 
          '' as NewDate,           
          '16 character str' as [Description], 
          0 as Movement,
          0 as intSort

   from #tmpTable j 
   where not exists ( 
        select 
               1 
        from #tmpTable x 
        where
               x.intID1 = j.intID1 
               and x.intID2 = j.intID2 
               and x.[Description] = '16 character str' 
   )
```

Comment: please post execution plan ,schema of tables involved and count of them

Comment: Why not just use `WHERE j.[Description] != '16 character str' `?

Comment: Because x and j are not the same record. We are joining the table on itself, to make sure that there is no record with a specific text that matches a certainId

Comment: do you have any unique id on tmpTable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the below query.

```
 INSERT INTO #tmpTable2 
     (intID3,intID4,intID5,intID6, 
      StaticDate,NewDate, 
      [Description],Change,intSort)
  SELECT DISTINCT 
      '' as intID3,           
      j.intID4,
      j.intID5, 
      j.intID6, 
      @dteDate1 as StaticDate, 
      '' as NewDate,           
      '16 character str' as [Description], 
      0 as Movement,
      0 as intSort
 FROM #tmpTable j 
       LEFT JOIN #tmpTable x  
             ON  x.intID1 = j.intID1 
                  AND x.intID2 = j.intID2 
                  AND x.[Description] = '16 character str' 
 WHERE x.intID1 IS NULL
```

Comment: Genius... I like this perspective... One question though...shouldn't it be a right join?

Comment: @Demian that is up to you.say your input data in table1 and you are trying to insert that data into table 2 with out entering the duplicate record , as per the script the input table  table1 should  come in the left side of the join (left join).